# Java GeneratedValue with sequence oddity (allocationSize = 1)

Tags: java, oracle, sequence

I have a working code, but I don't understand why it works:

```
public class FeatureInstalled implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "FEATURE_INSTALLED_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FEATURE_INSTALLED_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "FEATURE_INSTALLED_Sequence", sequenceName = "FEATURE_INSTALLED_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long featureInstalledId;
```

This gets the `FEATURE_INSTALLED_ID` from the sequence and uses it to insert a record.

I had the following code without `allocationSize` and although it appeared to use generated IDs, it had much larger `FEATURE_INSTALLED_IDs`:

```
public class FeatureInstalled implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "FEATURE_INSTALLED_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_Sequence", sequenceName = "FEATURE_INSTALLED_SEQ")
    private Long featureInstalledId;
```

Can someone explain to me why it works so strange without `allocationSize` and confirm that it works with it? Btw. There is also a trigger defined on the `FEATURE_INSTALLED-table` for `FEATURE_INSTALLED_ID` being NULL.

Comment: What do you mean by "it had much larger FEATURE_INSTALLED_IDs"?

Comment: The sequence is now at 38 but the  FEATURE_INSTALLED_ID of 2x5 entries were at about 1300 (I'm not sure of the precise value since I manually deleted these rows).

Answer (score 1):

The `allocationSize` attribute in the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation is optional, so if `allocationSize` is absent the `@SequenceGenerator` works fine with a default value at 50. Thus, the sequence generator increments the values by 50.

As mentioned in the documentation, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html), of the `@SequenceGenerator`:

> **allocationSize**
>
> public abstract int allocationSize (Optional) The amount to increment
>   by when allocating sequence numbers from the sequence. Default: 50